# yii2 gridview filter date

Tags: php, date, gridview, filter, yii2

I have in my gridview a date. I want to type it in the format `"29.11.2018"`. But in my table, the date is in the format `"2018-11-29"`. 
So it doesnt filter. 
my index.php:

```
[
'attribute'=>'enddate',
'format' => 'date',
'label' => 'Ablaufdatum'
],
```

my searchmodel:

```
 $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user', $this->user])
      ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'enddate', $this->enddate]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mysql:DATE_FORMAT()` AND `php:date()` to make sure it always compares in the same format and you can use any of the `=`,`>`,`<`,`>=`,`<=` operators rather than `like`.

Change the below code

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user', $this->user])
      ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'enddate', $this->enddate]);
```

to

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user', $this->user])
    ->andFilterWhere(
        [
            '=',
            new \yii\db\Expression('DATE_FORMAT(enddate, "%d.%m.%Y")'),
            date('d.m.Y', strtotime($this->enddate)),
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this before filter:

```
date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $this->enddate ) );
```