# How to change date format in filter search label after filtering the data in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I am working in yii2 framework, I want to display date format mm/dd/yyyy,but in my database format was yyyy-mm-dd. In model-search I converted the format mm/dd/yy and I am getting result. After in felter search label it showing as yyyy-mm-dd,I want display mm/dd/yyyy format.Please give suggestion.

UserSearch model

```
$query = User::find();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => $query,
    ]);

$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'start_date', trim($this->start_date)])

return $dataProvider;
```

index.php

```
<?= GridView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-bordered table-hover '],
         'headerRowOptions' => [
               'class' => 'thead-light',
          ],
          'rowOptions' =>function($model){
                 if($model->status == 0){
                     return ['class' =>'inactive-border-color',];
                  }
            },
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
             'columns' => [
                   [
                        'attribute' => 'start_date',
                         'format' => 'date',
                         'value' => 'termination_date',
                          'filterInputOptions' => [
                                 class'       => 'form-control',
                                 'placeholder' => 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                           ],
                    ],
              ]
]); ?>
```

I want display mm/dd/yyyy format in filter search .[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yii2 gridview filter date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541201/yii2-gridview-filter-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you use your `UserSearch` model to create data provider, the value in its `$start_date` is not used for filtering anymore so you can change it to the format you need for output. You simply need to add following code in your controller's action anywhere between creating the data provider and rendering the view.

```
$searchModel->start_date = \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($searchModel->start_date);
```

The other option is that instead of converting the value in $start_date property you will only convert it when creating data provider like this:

```
public function createDataProvider()
{
    $query = User::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'start_date', $this->normalizeDate($this->start_date)]);

    return $dataProvider;
}

protected function normalizeDate($date)
{
    //your code to convert date
    return $convertedDate;
}
```

Comment: you can just use `new \yii\db\Expression('DATE_FORMAT(enddate, "%d.%m.%Y")')` to format and match the column with the given date and desired format

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam althought that might work in some cases it is not the same. In mysql when you compare the DATE column to constant string using specific operators the values are converted to long int for comparison. The return value of DATE_FORMAT is string. If you use that the comparison would be made between two strings which may lead to different results.

However it will work with fine with LIKE operator that is used in this case.

Comment: i was talking about using the `yii\db\Expression` class inline, as the column might be using DateTime instead of Date only and you want to compare only the date part, and yes i agree about the comparison part it does compare as a string, and in that case we can do `date(start_date) < date '2019-08-01'` which makes `andFilterWhere(
                [
                    '>',
                    new Expression('date(start_date)'),
                    new Expression(" date '$this->start_date'")
                ]` or any other operator you want to use